# Django async update a single page template

Tags: django, templates, asynchronous

I have a django view with this function to get the data for a template:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
  context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
  context['extra_data'] = a_long_running_function()
  return context
```

The `extra_data` is displayed in a table. As the above function indicates, the page takes a long time to load due to calculation of `extra_data`.

So how can I show the page straight away, and then update the tablewhen `extra_data` is computed?

I understand how I can use celery to make `a_long_running_function` execute asynchronously, but I dont know how to then make the page (which is now loaded, but missing data for the table), get that data and update automatically?

Answer (score 11):

If you plan in going ahead with celery, you will need 2 views:

1.`viewA` that loads the main page (without the `extra_data` - maybe a spinning gif animation in it's place in the HTML, to convey to the user that there is still data to be loaded in the page). This view will also start the celery task (but will not wait for it to complete). It would look similar to:

```
def viewA(request):
    task = a_long_running_function.delay()

    return render_to_response('viewA.html', {'task_id': task.id})
```

2.`viewB` that will be accessed via AJAX after the user's browser loads `viewA` (it's purpose will be to provide the `extra_data` which was not loaded by `viewA`). It would look similar to:

```
def viewB(request, task_id):
    extra_data = a_long_running_function.AsyncResult(task_id) 

    if extra_data.ready():
       return render_to_response('viewB.html', {'extra_data': extra_data.get()})

    return HttpResponse('')
```

Once the user's browser finishes loading `viewA`, you will need a bit of javascript to start running [AJAX requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) every X seconds/minutes to `viewB` to attempt to retrieve the celery task result (based on the celery task id that is available). Once the AJAX request successfully retrieves the task result from `viewB`, it can make it visible to the user.

Comment: as per @Adrian Ghiuta's answer you can return `JsonResponse` instead of a whole page

Answer (score 6):

Anybody interested in asynchronous updating a template using AJAX can use [django-async-include](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-async-include) ([GitHub repository](https://github.com/diegojromerolopez/django-async-include)).

This project makes it easy changing an static block inclusion to a asynchronous one. That's perfect for inclusion of computational-heavy template block.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of this project.

Comment: Why not explain exactly how to use your project to acomplish the problem described in this question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you plan on continuing to make references to this tool, I suggest you read [How to not be a spammer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) to make sure you don't get your posts marked as spam.

Comment: I'm not spamming with "my tool" because I only mentioned here once because a) it's open source, b) it could be helpful to the OP.

How did I find this old question? By making a search in SO.

What do I win with some people using this extremely simple Django application? Nothing.

Comment: This answer is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348617/spam-or-not-thats-the-question)