# Trying to get Django app to update variables that are taken from an external python script

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I've recently been working with a Raspberry Pi, and I've hooked up a temperature/humidity sensor and have a python script that reads the values and logs them and the time. I'm currently constructing a Django app, and my goal is to have it display a webpage that will show the current values taken in from the sensor in real time.

As of now, views.py is taking in the latest values from the log and passing those to the html template when it's rendered like so:

```
    return render(request, 'control_panel.html',{'humidity': relativeH, 'tempC': temperatureC, 'tempF': temperatureF, 'date': full_date})
```

Those variables are referenced in control_panel.html. Right now, the webpage loads properly, displaying the values from when the page was loaded. However, I'm not sure how to get it to keep updating the variables on the page so it's always up to date. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The general strategy will be to use javascript to make an asynchronous request to update the DOM with the correct values every `t` seconds.  You will want to look into [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).  In the context of Django, this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188499/django-async-update-a-single-page-template) may be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at Ajax, I just wasn't sure how to exactly implement it in a way that helped me. Is celery going to be necessary to update it every t seconds?

Comment: No, you don't need celery. Instead of loading everything in the template, you want to make a separate API view that serves just the data from the sensor log. Then you make the javascript on the page call the API and update the page on regular basis.